# Google Cloud Dataproc Installing libopencv

Tags: opencv, debian, google-cloud-dataproc

I created a cloud dataproc cluster and in my initialization script I try to install libopencv-dev but I keep getting unmet dependencies error:

```
sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libopencv-dev : Depends: libopencv-objdetect-dev (= 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1+deb8u1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libopencv-highgui-dev (= 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1+deb8u1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libopencv-legacy-dev (= 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1+deb8u1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libopencv-contrib-dev (= 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1+deb8u1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libopencv-videostab-dev (= 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1+deb8u1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libopencv-superres-dev (= 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1+deb8u1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libopencv-ocl-dev (= 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1+deb8u1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libcv-dev (= 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1+deb8u1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libhighgui-dev (= 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1+deb8u1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libcvaux-dev (= 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1+deb8u1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I don't know what is wrong, I tried to create a compute engine with debian 8 and ran the same command on it and it works correctly but not on the machines created for the dataproc cluster, does anyone know what is the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems they use backports so to install libopencv-dev I had to install it from the backports repo with this command:

```
sudo apt-get -t jessie-backports install libopencv-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing with aptitude

Run the following

sudo apt install aptitude -y
sudo aptitude install libopencv-dev